# How to add a header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with headers id,n and t containing duplicate id and after calling groupby and then size() and extra column with no header is generated given below.Now how do I add an extra column header 'count' associated with the values of the 4th column values so that it becomes ['id','n','t','count']

id   n    t
7   2   Y     4
7   2   N     6
8   3   Y     2
8   9   N     3
9   1   Y     5
9   6   N     7

Comment: It's unlikely that this really has no name, what does `df.columns.tolist()` show? you can then rename that column using `rename` or just assign directly `df.columns = ['id','n','t','count']`

Comment: how did you create/populate the data frame? you can create an empty data frame by simply df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=(id','n','t','count'))

Comment: @EdChum: After using this operations df_ = df.groupby(['id','n','t']).size() on df dataframe the result is as above.

Comment: Well you performed an aggregation using groupby so this is completely different to your original problem description, can you edit your question to include this as it matters, anyway you'd have to call `reset_index` on the `groupby` and then rename

Comment: @EdChum: This is how I solved it. Called, df = df.reset_index(), it generates a header with 0 and then calling , df.rename(columns={0:'count'}, inplace=True) . Now calling df.columns.values gives ['id','n','t','count']. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

As @EdChum mentioned `reset_index` has to be called on `groupby` and then rename. Pandas generates a header 0 for the extra column

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={0:'count'}, inplace=True)
```